# Sanitizing input for display in view when using simple_format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, xss, sanitization, html-sanitizing

I'm trying to figure out the right way to display comments such that newlines and links are displayed. I know that usually, you should display user-inputs only when escaping html with h(). That of course won't display newlines or links, so I found the simple_format and auto_link methods.

What I am now doing is: simple_format(santize(auto_link(comment.text)))

Is this the right way to do this, and is it still safe from XSS attacks?

Thanks!
Eric

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to the last ryanb screencast [XSS Protection in Rails 3](http://railscasts.com/episodes/204-xss-protection-in-rails-3)

Cheers